# What is $(j,\epsilon)$-normality?

Tags: definition, real-numbers

In looking at the concept of normality for real numbers I have come across the notion of $(j,\epsilon)$-normality, but cannot find a definition for this. could anyone explain what this term means?

Comment: It might help if you stated where you found this.

Comment: @RobertIsrael http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa16/aa1632.pdf

Comment: @Austin thx 4 the edit

Comment: According to the second paragraph, it looks like references [14] and [15] of this paper might be useful.

Comment: @Robert good point. unfortunately Stoneham's other paper in Acta Arithmetica also assumes the reader knows the meaning, and I haven't been able to access Besicovitch's paper referred to. however, on examination of the text I think I need something rather more elementary than this. I have at least gleaned some orientation from the brief historical survey in Stoneham's work referenced above.